# Image load error only fires sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a classified style website with 50-100 images per page all loading from different sources at once. Sometimes I get a 404 and I'm trying to handle that.

On each element containing images I have this script:

```
$el.find('img').one('error', function() {           
    console.log('broken image detected');
    // Replace broken image with something else
}).each(function() {
    if(this.complete || $(this).height() > 0){
        $(this).load();
    }
});
```

But it seems to fire at random, not picking up all 404 load errors - especially at the beginning of the page where literally none of the 404s are detected. Towards the end of the page it looks a bit better.

What's going on?

I should add, that this piece of JavaScript is not initialised BEFORE the entire DOM has finished loading, but I was under the impression that the .each part would cater for this?

Another idea would be to insert an inline load error detector:

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" onerror="window.errorHandler(this);">
```

But since my JavaScript is modular in design I would prefer to avoid this.

--- EDIT ---

I have solved this problem by inserting an inline script on the onerror handler. It's not super elegant, but it works because the listener is inserted at the same time as the src attribute. Also it is not dependent on jQuery.

I have done a slight work around in my front-end code to cater for this, by exposing a function to window.

Comment: Could it be a timeout issue? Have you tried delaying the above jQuery code for a second to see if it picks up the errors better?

Comment: Should it really be _one_ in `.one('error', function()` and not `.on('error', function()` ?

Comment: I get same results with .on('error') as with .one('error');

Comment: And btw, the inline solution works EVERY time. It's just bad application design when you got modular code.

Comment: Did you try putting this code in a document ready block to check if it handles the errors better (`$(function() {})`)?

Comment: `$.one()` is perfectly valid, and a very useful method. Maybe Sidney is right, sometimes you just forget the `$(document).ready()` statement!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All listeners to handle load or error events must be set BEFORE src property of img is setted.

Comment: Yup. This is certainly the case. I've done some more testing, and my problem is, that the listener is attached before jQuery loads and hence my code is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You may implement lazy loading (i.e. insert `<img>` paths in a data attribute, put a fake pixel in the `src`  attribute, and load the real images on DOM load with jQuery or JavaScript). You then shouldn't face any timing problems.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="gallery">
  <img id="img1" 
       src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAI=" 
       data-src="imagethatgives404.gif"
       width="200" height="200">
  <img id="img2" 
       src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAI=" 
       data-src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg"
       width="200" height="200">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $el = $('#gallery');

   $el.find('[data-src]')
      .one('error', function(e) {
         console.log(e.target.id + ' is broken');
         // Replace broken image with something else
      })
      .each(function(index,element){
         element.src = $(element).data('src');
      });
});
```

The `width` and `height` on the `<img>` tags are used to show how dimensions are preserved.

Example [here](http://jsbin.com/jeliqixibo/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

Comment: This is a good approach, but will hurt SEO, since the pixel is most likely what a given search engine will see - but thanks for the tip.

Comment: Due to increased page speed, it doesn't hurt but boost SEO. Google it and check recent articles, not the old out-of-date stuff.